# CodeIgniter form_radio with set_value

Tags: codeigniter, radio-button

I am having a bit of trouble with my form and radio buttons, with input text I do this:

```
<?php echo form_input('lastname', set_value('lastname'), 'id=lastname'); ?>
<?php echo form_error('lastname'); ?>
```

and when the validation runs and that input field that is filled out gets the valued returned...what I am looking for is a way to do this with radio buttons

```
<tr><td><?php echo form_label('Gender: ', 'gender'); ?></td><td><?php echo form_label('Male', 'male') . form_radio('gender', 'M', '', 'id=male'); ?><br><?php echo form_label('Female', 'female') . form_radio('gender', 'F', '', 'id=female'); ?></td><td><?php echo form_error('gender'); ?></td></tr>
```

as you can see both my radio buttons have values already F or M.....how do I have the button that is selected returned selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked well for me. Even though I didnt use form_helper, this was much easier way. Everyone face issue to take input for gender field :)

```
               <input id="gender" name="gender" type="radio" class="" <?php if($gender=='0') echo "checked='checked'"; ?> value="0" <?php echo $this->form_validation->set_radio('gender', 0); ?> />
                <label for="gender" class="">Male</label>

                <input id="gender" name="gender" type="radio" class="" <?php if($gender=='1') echo "checked='checked'"; ?> value="1" <?php echo $this->form_validation->set_radio('gender', 1); ?> />
                <label for="gender" class="">Female</label>

                <input id="gender" name="gender" type="radio" class="" <?php if($gender=='2') echo "checked='checked'"; ?> value="2" <?php echo $this->form_validation->set_radio('gender', 2); ?> />
                <label for="gender" class="">Others</label>
```

I hope it will help someone :)

Comment: Just a minor comment, the {} braces are missing from the if clause

Comment: @RomanT, considering that there is only statement with "if" condition, braces are not mandatory, but good to have.

Answer (score 10):

From the user guide: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html

> `form_radio()`
>
> This function is identical in all respects to the form_checkbox()
>   function above except that is sets it as a "radio" type.

So reading further:

> `form_checkbox()`
>
> Lets you generate a checkbox field. Simple example:
>
> ```
> echo form_checkbox('newsletter', 'accept', TRUE);
> ```
>
> Would produce:
>
> ```
> <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" value="accept" checked="checked" />
> ```
>
> The **third parameter** contains a boolean TRUE/FALSE to determine whether
>   the box should be checked or not.

So in your case, it might be something like this:

```
// Pass boolean value to third param
// Example:
$radio_is_checked = $this->input->post('gender') === 'F';

echo form_radio('gender', 'F', $radio_is_checked, 'id=female');
```

Since `set_radio()` just returns a string `checked="checked"`, you could wedge it in to the fourth paramter if you really wanted to but it makes for some ugly looking code:

```
echo form_radio('gender', 'F', NULL, 'id="female" '.set_radio('gender', 'F'));
```

Answer (score 6):

I use Ternary Operator for this.
Suppose you got return value of "M" (Male). I am making $selected variable for example and assume that it has value of M.

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <?php echo form_label('Gender: ', 'gender'); ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo form_label('Male', 'male') . form_radio(array('name' => 'gender', 'value' => 'M', 'checked' => ('M' == $selected) ? TRUE : FALSE, 'id' => 'male')); ?><br>
        <?php echo form_label('Female', 'female') . form_radio(array('name' => 'gender', 'value' => 'F', 'checked' => ('F' == $selected) ? TRUE : FALSE, 'id' => 'female')); ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo form_error('gender'); ?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works forsure....

```
<tr><td><?php echo form_label('Gender: ', 'gender'); ?></td><td><?php echo form_label('Male', 'male') . form_radio(array("name"=>"gender","id"=>"male","value"=>"M", 'checked'=>set_radio('gender', 'M', FALSE))); ?><br><?php echo form_label('Female', 'female') . form_radio(array("name"=>"gender","id"=>"female","value"=>"F", 'checked'=>set_radio('gender', 'F', FALSE))); ?></td><td><?php echo form_error('gender'); ?></td></tr>
```

wrote my radio buttons like so

```
<?php form_radio(array("name"=>"gender","id"=>"female","value"=>"F", 'checked'=>set_radio('gender', 'F', FALSE))); ?>
```

Comment: `checked` accepts a Boolean, [while `set_radio` returns `checked="checked"`](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/helpers/form_helper.php#L808).

Comment: The reason this works is because CI is nice enough to [correct your error](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/helpers/form_helper.php#L389) and convert the value of `checked` to a legal one, with any other attribute this would output something like `attr=" checked="checked""`.

Answer (score -2):

```
$_fldProyectoMostrar = array(
"id"        => "_FLDPROYDER",
"name"      => "_FLDPROYDER"
);


<?php echo form_radio($_fldProyectoMostrar, "FALSE",    set_radio("_FLDPROYDER", "FALSE", TRUE)); ?>NO

<?php echo form_radio($_fldProyectoMostrar, "TRUE",     set_radio("_FLDPROYDER", "TRUE", FALSE )); ?>SI
```

Donde el el segundo valor del set radio, debe ser = al string value del form_radio